# Owl Carousel Navigation not working

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have 2 carousels, one under another, and i am using "navContainer" function to change the position of the navigation arrows (i am placing them above the slider).

When i have one slider, that works, but when i have 2 (or more), navigation for both sliders is located in first "navhere" div. Instead of that, each of navigation buttons should be in its own div.

You can get better idea of what i am talking here : http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/226/

Code is:

```
<div class="about">
    <div id="navhere"></div> <!-- This is where nav should appear -->
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><h4>About</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>Us</h4></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
    <div id="navhere"></div> <!-- This is where nav should appear -->
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><h4>Contact</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>Form</h4></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery is

```
 .owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        dots:false,
        items:1,
        navContainer: '#navhere'
    })
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/226/. Yes, it shows two because of two sliders. Each slider will have its own nav.

Comment: it does, they slide, but navigation for both sliders is stored in first "navhere" div. they should be each in their own div. aka, second div "navhere" is empty, and that is where the navigation for second slide should be shown

Comment: remove the navcontainer from script & manage thier position via css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot duplicate the values of `id`. It has to be unique. That's the reason.

Still. According to [this issue](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/171), **multiple nav hasn't been yet implemented!**

Comment: if i use classes instead of id's, would it be possible then?

Comment: shame, i dont know what to do now, but in anycase, thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: if i am not being boring (i think i am tough...) could you take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/b5bqk68j/24/? If you have any comments, it would mean a lot...

Comment: @Vlidurno Checking now.

Comment: @Vlidurno Check the dotsEach option: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html#dotseach

Comment: i think i found a solution :) https://jsfiddle.net/9nm4ctv9/847/ But again, thanks a bunch for helping out!

Comment: thanks a bunch! i found out the solution for pagination : 
appendDots:$(this).siblings('.pagination'), but this is only if the .pagination is sibiling to slider. what if it is one level up?

Comment: Ha ha... Okay... So add it as a sibling then.

Comment: haha, yea, i know that i am boring and ask too much, sorry :D Actually, not only that it is level up, it is 2 levels up :D Once again, thanks for all the help, enjoy ur day!

Comment: LoL. Nothing like that. Great... Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

if your view-able items are less than the total items then the navigation will disable automatically. in another word you must have enough items to view Navigation which offer from Owl-carouse

Comment: this should be a comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

Navigation not working

```
.owlCarousel({
        startPosition: 0,
        margin: 20,
        dots: true,
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        nav: true,
        pagination :true,
        autoplayTimeout:6000,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{

                items:1
            },
            480:{

                items:2
            },
            568:{

                items:2
            },
            667:{

                items:2
            },
            768:{

                items:3
            },
            1024:{
                items:5
            }
        }
    });
});
```